# Unity Coroutine IEnumerator that uses Generics can't exist as the same method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, coroutine

I have a simple Unity method that allows me to fade an object over time by changing it's alpha colour value. This worked fine as a co-routine with an IEnumerator for a specific type like an `Image`. I wanted this to also work with `TMP_Text`, so  I extended this method to work on any object type that is of type `Graphic` which all have `color`, like an image, text etc using generics.

However, Generics requires the method be static, but the IEnumerator requires that it be an instance method.

How do I get around this?

Please note that I'm not asking for suggestions about the fade code itself or that it has a callback etc.

```cs
private IEnumerator FadeAndDestroy<T>(this T fadeObject, float fadeDuration, UnityAction callback) where T : Graphic //Helper Function? //List of objects that need the colour param to change?
{
    float elapsedTime = 0f;
    Color startingColor = fadeObject.color;
    Color targetColor = new Color(startingColor.r, startingColor.g, startingColor.b, 0);

    while (elapsedTime < fadeDuration)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        float fraction = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 1f, elapsedTime / fadeDuration);
        fadeObject.color = Color.Lerp(startingColor, targetColor, fraction); //float fraction = SmoothStep01(elapsedTime / fadeDuration);  //SoftestInSoftOut01
        yield return null;
    }

    callback.Invoke();

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

UPDATE 1:
In its current form, the compiler complains `Extension method must be defined in a none-generic static class`

So I've changed the method and class to be static.

However, because the class derives from `MonoBehaviour` this causes the error ```Static class 'testclass' cannot derive from type 'MonoBehaviour'.

So I've been able to fix one problem and create another.

Here is the updated code that now includes the class

```cs
public static class testclass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static IEnumerator FadeAndDestroy<T>(this T fadeObject, float fadeDuration, UnityAction callback) where T : Graphic //Helper Function? //List of objects that need the colour param to change?
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        Color startingColor = fadeObject.color;
        Color targetColor = new Color(startingColor.r, startingColor.g, startingColor.b, 0);

        while (elapsedTime < fadeDuration)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            float fraction = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 1f, elapsedTime / fadeDuration);
            fadeObject.color = Color.Lerp(startingColor, targetColor, fraction); //float fraction = SmoothStep01(elapsedTime / fadeDuration);  //SoftestInSoftOut01
            yield return null;
        }

        callback.Invoke();

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: "However, Generics requires the method be static" - what makes you think that? "the IEnumerator requires that it be an instance method" - what makes you think that?

Comment: (It's entirely possible to write generic instance methods, and also entirely possible to write static methods returning an `IEnumerator`.)

Comment: The fact that it's an *extension* method requires it to be a static method in a static class though...

Comment: Care to provide an answer @JonSkeet to get it to work?

Comment: How can I provide an answer when your question is based on invalid assumptions? I don't know why you believe you can't write a static method returning an `IEnumerator`, nor why you think you can't write an instance method using generics.

Comment: I've updated my OP with more data in 'Update 1'. I've displayed the whole class this time. If you can get past 'my assumptions' and provide a way to make the code work, that would be great @JonSkeet

Comment: Fundamentally, if you need this to be an extension method, it needs to be in a static, non-generic class, just like the compiler error says, which means you won't be able to derive from anything. We don't know whether you *do* actually need it to be an extension method though, nor whether you really need it to be in a class that derives from MonoBehavior. Fundamentally we don't know nearly enough about the requirements to propose a solution.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to move this forward @PhillipZoghbi but I've managed to find a working solution myself. I'm going to post it now as a solution.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to derive from `MonoBehaviour` for the extension class (you can't anyways)? Perhaps a static method with generic `static IEnumerator FadeAndDestroy<T>` is enough. Also, make sure it has `public` accessor.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution to the problem myself. Here's what I did:

1. I created a new class that is `static` and no longer inherits from
   `MonoBehaviour`
2. I moved the `FadeAndDestroy` method to the new class and also made it `static`
3. Because the new class no longer inherits from `MonoBehaviour` which some of the methods rely on, I did two things:
4. Added a new parameter to the method to pass in the object to destroy.
5. Also the `Monobehavior` `Destroy` method had to be called in a slightly different way
6. This static method and class now gets called from the original class which is unaltered

Here's the new code:

```
public static class GUI_Effects
{
    public static IEnumerator FadeAndDestroy<T>(this T fadeObject, float fadeDuration, UnityAction callback, GameObject GOToDestroy) where T : Graphic //Helper Function? //List of objects that need the colour param to change?
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        Color startingColor = fadeObject.color;
        Color targetColor = new Color(startingColor.r, startingColor.g, startingColor.b, 0);

        while (elapsedTime < fadeDuration)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            float fraction = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 1f, elapsedTime / fadeDuration);
            fadeObject.color = Color.Lerp(startingColor, targetColor, fraction); //float fraction = SmoothStep01(elapsedTime / fadeDuration);  //SoftestInSoftOut01
            yield return null;
        }

        callback.Invoke();

        MonoBehaviour.Destroy(GOToDestroy);
    }
}
```

Comment: `MonoBehaviour.Destroy` is actually `UnityEngine.Object.Destroy` and `fraction  = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 1f, elapsedTime / fadeDuration);` .. why no simply `fraction = elapsedTime / fadeDuration` ?

Comment: Because I'm going to be swapping the Lerp out for another function once this works so that it's not a linear fade. @derHugo

Comment: in that case I would still use this but add an additional `AnimationCurve` parameter and then use [`Evaluate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html) ;)

Comment: Yeah that might be something I do down the road, but currently I'm using the methods shown in this post for now:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/equivalent-to-lerp-or-smoothstep-but-with-custom-curves.229966/#post-2752127
I'll have to compare features and performance at some point @derHugo